# Crodova, inappbrowser execute script gives: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm using Cordova and I want to execute a piece of code in the inappbrowser.
I have the following code to accomplish this. First of all, the function executeScript is never executed. I can't break there. But also, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

This is the actual code:

```
inappbrowser_window.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {     
    inappbrowser_window.executeScript({code : 'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];'}, function(txt){
        ...
        //this is inside another function that i'm calling.
        // dont know if its relevant. Included just in case.
        try{
           JSON.parse(txt)
        }catch(e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        ...

    });
});
```

Does anyone know what I;m missing? Is there something obvious that I need to do and didn't?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Jenia.

Comment: Are you sure parsing everything inside `body` tag is what you want?

Comment: ummm no. just the textContent, or whatever it's called. but i doesnt matter. The code itself itsnt executed and I get a infinite loop error. Do you think that what I did mostly is correct? It that usually the way to proceed? This kind of form is typical?

Comment: Usually this means that you have objects referencing each other (ex A -> B  and B -> A). Can you provide an example of the JSON you are trying to load?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm just inserting a console.log statement and I'm still having the same issues. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the serialisation problem occurs in the inAppBrowser plugin and not in your code:

In order to deliver the result of the script execution to the callback function, `inappbrowser_window.executeScript()` will have to serialise the result of the code block executed in the inAppBrowser.

If the result of the code block is a complex object containing circular references, `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` will fire, even if you do not try to serialise the data yourself.